# Unable to fit hypergeometric function

Tags: horizontal-alignment, fit, scientific-notation

I am unable to fit a *6F5 hypergeometric function* in one line. Can you suggest an edit to fix it? If you have a better notation to write then you can.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{bm}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\fontfamily{cmr}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\renewenvironment{abstract}
 {\quotation\small\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}\par\smallskip
  {\centering\bfseries\abstractname\par}\medskip}
 {\par\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}\endquotation}
 \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.3mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\section{Triangle}
\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}
I_2=\frac{(s)^{-a_{12345}+D}\Gamma(D/2-a_5)\Gamma(a_{12345}-D)\Gamma(-a_{23}+D/2)\Gamma(-a_{14}+D)\Gamma(-a_{1235}+D)\Gamma(-a_{1245}+D)}{\Gamma(a_3)\Gamma(a_4)\Gamma(a_5)\Gamma(-a_{12345}+3D/2)\Gamma(-a_{235}+D)\Gamma(-a_{145}+D)}\\
\times _{6}F_{5}\left[\begin{array}{l}
{1+a_{12345}-3D/2,\,1+a_{235}-D,\,1+a_{145}-D,\,a_{12345}-D,\,1/2+(a_{1234})/2-D/2,\,1+(a_{1234})/2-D/2} \\
{1+a_{1234}-D,\,1+a_{1235}-D,\,1+a_{1245}-D,\,1+a_{23}-D/2,\,1+a_{14}-D/2}
\end{array} ; -\frac{4 m^{2}}{s} \right]
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this way it looks ok. Of course it is still a little crowded, but the equation fits in the margins. I mostly changed the fractions like `D/2` to `\frac{D}{2}` to save some space, and changed the size of the parameters of the hypergeometric function to `\scriptsize`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}
I_2 = \frac{(s)^{-a_{12345}+D}\Gamma(\frac{D}{2}-a_5)\Gamma(a_{12345}-D)\Gamma(-a_{23}+\frac{D}{2})\Gamma(-a_{14}+D)\Gamma(-a_{1235}+D)\Gamma(-a_{1245}+D)}{\Gamma(a_3)\Gamma(a_4)\Gamma(a_5)\Gamma(-a_{12345}+\frac{3D}{2})\Gamma(-a_{235}+D)\Gamma(-a_{145}+D)}\\
\times {}_{6}F_{5}
\!\left[ \hspace{-3mm} \begin{aligned}
& \scriptstyle
    1+a_{12345}-\frac{3D}{2},\,1+a_{235}-D,\,1+a_{145}-D,\,a_{12345}-D,\,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{(a_{1234})}{2}-\frac{D}{2},\,1+\frac{(a_{1234})}{2}-\frac{D}{2} \\
& \scriptstyle
    1+a_{1234}-D,\,1+a_{1235}-D,\,1+a_{1245}-D,\,1+a_{23}-\frac{D}{2},\,1+a_{14}-\frac{D}{2}
\end{aligned} ; -\frac{4 m^{2}}{s} \right]
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Here's another solution in which the hypergeometric function is a little bigger; its arguments are in `\textstyle` and not in `\scriptstyle`. For the function to fit in the line, I enclosed the binary operators + and - in braces so that they are not interpreted as binary operators anymore, and there is much less space around them.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
I_2 = \frac{(s)^{-a_{12345}+D}\Gamma(\frac{D}{2}-a_5)\Gamma(a_{12345}-D)\Gamma(-a_{23}+\frac{D}{2})\Gamma(-a_{14}+D)\Gamma(-a_{1235}+D)\Gamma(-a_{1245}+D)}{\Gamma(a_3)\Gamma(a_4)\Gamma(a_5)\Gamma(-a_{12345}+\frac{3D}{2})\Gamma(-a_{235}+D)\Gamma(-a_{145}+D)}\\
\times {}_{6}F_{5}
\!\left[ \begin{aligned}
& \textstyle
    1{+}a_{12345}{-}\frac{3D}{2},\,
    1{+}a_{235}{-}D,\,
    1{+}a_{145}{-}D,\,
    a_{12345}{-}D,\,
    \frac{1}{2}{+}\frac{(a_{1234})}{2}{-}\frac{D}{2},\,
    1{+}\frac{(a_{1234})}{2}{-}\frac{D}{2} \\
& \textstyle
    1{+}a_{1234}{-}D,\,
    1{+}a_{1235}{-}D,\,
    1{+}a_{1245}{-}D,\,
    1{+}a_{23}{-}\frac{D}{2},\,
    1{+}a_{14}{-}\frac{D}{2}
\end{aligned} ; -\frac{4 m^{2}}{s} \right]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Also, it is not related to the alignment problem, but if you write `\times _{6}F_{5}`, the "6" in subscript will be typeset as a subscript of the `\times` symbol. To make it appear on the left of the "F", you can add empty braces `{}` before the `_{6}`, as in the example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It would be better if the hypergeometric function fills whole of the 2nd Line. This makes its parameters bigger and more visible. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Yes! I added another solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is perfect!